# How can oscillations be there with constant voltage source in RLC circuit?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, vibrations

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pnfZjGIyKVw&list=PLyQSN7X0ro22WeXM2QCKJm2NP_xHpGV89&index=4) the professor closes the switch at $t=0$ and the circuit produces damping oscillations(charge) before settling to a steady value. How is it possible?

I understand the oscillations in LC tank circuit with some initial charge on capacitor.
But I can't seem to understand how oscillations are produced in below circuit while the capacitor is charging with a **DC** source. Any help?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The current that flows through an ideal voltage source (battery symbol) is completely independent of the voltage. So far as the current is concerned, the "battery" is no different from a zero ohm wire.

Comment: Ahh so at t=0, the current slowly rises and energy is stored in both inductor and capacitor. Even when the voltage on capacitor equals the input voltage, the inductor further OVERcharges the capacitor because the current through inductor is continuous. Then the capacitor charges the inductor... Makes sense... thank you:) @SolomonSlow

Comment: Yes. That's right. The presence of the voltage source adds a D.C. offset to the waveform, but otherwise, because the capacitor blocks any D.C. current, it's as if the voltage source wasn't there at all.

Comment: @SolomonSlow just a quick question, the capacitor finally charges to the FULL input voltage right?

Comment: I'm asking because I'm getting a different answer with math for steady state, but I know/feel it should charge to FULL input voltage

Comment: im getting steady state final value as $V_{in}* LC$ using particular solution method: $y_p = \dfrac{V_{in}e^{0t}}{p(0)}$, but i think the correct value should be $V_{in}$ something wrong:(

Comment: Nvm, found the mistake!!